# triggering multiple backendcalls with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to trigger a backend call multiple times using an effect, the calls are started but are being canceled. I'm unsure if it's an issue with the effect or an HTTP error. My effect is triggering the calls properly, they just don't get finalised.

I'm using a third party API. The call I'm making uses OData and the response is limited to 500 items per call. The total amount of records I need is 6440, which means I have to call the backend 13 times to get all my data. Before the API did not supply a call to get the total count of the query, but they modified that so I could upgrade my algorithm.

Without the count I did the following steps which worked but was slow because it runs synchronously:

1. calling the backend,
2. waiting for the result,
3. Save the results,
4. if the resultset had 500 items, recursively call the effect again using a higher skipvalue, and starting back at step 1, else stop the loop

Now I've changed the code to work asynchronously after getting the resultset count. I'm dispatching the action array after getting the count, here's the coding I'm using for that:

```
    loadCollectionCount$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(this.loadActionGroup.loadItemCollection),
            withLatestFrom(this.store.select(this.loadedStatus)),
            switchMap(([{ }, loaded]) => {
                if (!loaded) {
                    return this.loadService.getListCount(this.filterValue).pipe(
                        switchMap((result: number) =>{
                            let act: Action[] = [ this.loadActionGroup.loadItemCollectionCountSuccess({ count: result }) ];
                            for (let i = 0; i < result; i = i + 500) {
                                act.push(this.loadActionGroup.loadItemCollectionWithSkip({skip:i}));
                            }
                            return act;
                        } ),
                        catchError(error => {
                            console.log(error, `${this.typeName} effects - loadCollection`);
                            return of(this.loadActionGroup.loadItemFailure({ error: { ...error } }))
                        })
                    )
                } else {
                    return of();
                }
            })
        )
    );

    loadItemCollectionWithSkip$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(this.loadActionGroup.loadItemCollectionWithSkip),
            switchMap((action) => {
                return this.loadService.getListOdata(this.filterValue, action.skip).pipe(
                    map((items: T[]) =>{
                        return this.loadActionGroup.loadItemSuccess({ items })
                    })
                )
            })
        )
    );
```

However, this results in the first 12 calls getting canceled, and only the last one completing, as you can see in the network page results. So the actions get triggered and the calls are made correctly, they're just not being finalized.

[image: Network page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is here

```
switchMap((action) => {
  return this.loadService.getListOdata(this.filterValue, action.skip)
```

switchMap operator cancels previous event "handling" when new event comes. That is why you have http requests cancels in the network tab. Easy fix is to replace it with `concatMap`. That way they will be fired one by one in order. The bad thing here is they won't be getting data in parallel.

there is a way with `mergeMap`, but the order won't be saved in a simple way. To preserve order I would recommend to pass nesessary metadata to the action and handle it in the reducer correctly

```
  mergeMap((action) => {
   return this.loadService.getListOdata(this.filterValue, action.skip).pipe(
     map((items: T[]) =>{
       return this.loadActionGroup.loadItemSuccess({ items, skip: action.skip })
     })
   )
  })
```

Comment: aha, you're right, but that indeed brings me back to the original synchronous path. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, `mergeMap` was actually what I'm looking for! If you add that to your answer I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks a lot